# Using AirDrop under iOS 17, my custom files open in the Files app instead of my app

Tags: ios, ios17, airdrop

When attempting to AirDrop a file my app creates, extension .PTW, the receiving device does not open the file in my app, instead it saves it in the Files app, in the Download folder. Before iOS 17, it used to open directly in my app.

My UTI seems to be configured correctly as per https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers?language=objc .

I also tried configuring my info.plist file as per the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45154660/1515515 . Same result.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Looks it started happening from iOS 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an intentional change in iOS 17.

ref: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/737971?page=1#767265022

Comment: Thank you. At least, now I know why and what to tell my users.

Comment: @perdrix
Hi, I have the same issue as perdirix. iOS17 device opens custom UTI on file app (not my app). I cannot open the link scliu provided, but how did you solve this problem?

Were you able to open AirDrop file in your app?

Comment: @Yuuu Hello. I have not check the latest information regarding this problem, but by the time I reply to this question, the problem seems to be intentional and can not be solved.

Comment: Exactly like @scliu said. I complained in Apple Feedback Assistant but they just closed my case. I was not able to find a workaround.